# nlme and lme4 Ignoring squared terms

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to build on a standard translog demand function, which is:

```
lnY = lnP + lnZ + lnY*lnZ + lnY^2 + lnZ^2
```

Where `Y` = demand, `P` = price, and `Z` = income.

However, when I include the squared terms in nlme or lme4, they just ignore them. I've tried:

```
model <- lme(asinh(gallons) ~ asinh(rprc) + asinh(rexp) + asinh(rexp)*asinh(rexp) + asinh(rprc)*asinh(rprc) + asinh(rprc)*asinh(rexp), random=~1|cuid, data = data)
```

and I've tried:

```
model <- lme(asinh(gallons) ~ asinh(rprc) + asinh(rexp) + asinh(rexp)^2 + asinh(rprc)^2 + asinh(rprc)*asinh(rexp), random=~1|cuid, data = data)
```

And I've tried the equivalents for lmer.

The squared terms just don't show up in summary(model), and I know they're being ignored because I've created separate vectors with the squared terms and passed those in and the estimates are different.

Anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In formulas, the term `^2` is used to create interactions of variables. For example, `(x+y+z)^2` creates the main effects and all possible interactions with two variables, i.e., `x + y + z  + x:y + x:z + y:z`. Hence, `x^2` inside a formula is the same as `x`.

Furthermore, also `*` is used to create interactions, For example, `x*y` creates `x + y + x:y`. Hence, `x*x` inside a formula is the same as `x`.

To create the squared value inside a formula, you have to use the function `I`, i.e., `I(x^2)` or `I(x*x)`.

```
lme(asinh(gallons) ~ asinh(rprc) + asinh(rexp) +
      I(asinh(rexp)^2) + I(asinh(rprc)^2) + asinh(rprc)*asinh(rexp), 
    random=~1|cuid, data = data)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am indeed trying to create an interaction. I want price to interact with itself, for example, because the marginal impact of price changes depending on the price.

Comment: @user2611609 Can't you use the squared term?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I misunderstood. I didnt realise it worked like this. I can actually simplify my overall formula code now as well. Thanks!